# new field in dataset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to transition from using SAS to Python, which I am enjoying.  I found a nice SQL to Pandas guide which helped a lot, but there's a couple of things I do in SAS that I'm not certain how to do in Pandas:

```
/*  looks at variable within a dataset and assigns it to high, med, low */

data scores;

set scores;

if score_value >= 80 then score_cat = "high";

else if score_value >= 50 then score_cat = "med";

else score_cat = "low";

run;



/*  looks at the value of a particular variable and deletes the record */

data people;

set people;

if trim(name)="" then delete;

run;
```

I'm sure this is pretty easy to do, but I'm just not seeing it at the moment.  T

Thanks!
JT

Comment: Your question is a bit broad I think you need to look at the excellent online docs and come back with your attempts that didn't work, in particular check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) and [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html) out

Answer (score 1):

- To categorize values, you could use
  [pandas.cut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.cut.html).
- To remove rows with empty strings, make a boolean mask, e.g. `df['people'] != ''`, and select rows with `df[...]` or [`df.loc[...]`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html):

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'score':[0,1,49,50,80,81,100],
                   'people':['', 'A', 'B', '', 'D', '', 'F']})
#   people  score
# 0             0
# 1      A      1
# 2      B     49
# 3            50
# 4      D     80
# 5            81
# 6      F    100


df['cat'] = pd.cut(df['score'], bins=[0,50,80,100], include_lowest=True,
                   labels=['low', 'med', 'high'])

df = df[df['people'] != '']
print(df)
```

yields

```
  people  score   cat
1      A      1   low
2      B     49   low
4      D     80   med
6      F    100  high
```